# git fetch origin rejected

Tags: git

Suddenly I can't fetch anymore from remote...

```
$git fetch origin
! [rejected]        master     -> origin/master  (non-fast-forward)
```

I don't know what to look for or what happened, since it was working until now.
There is not much to say about configuration:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://xx.xxx.xx/project.git
    fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

Other colleagues probably pushed something on the remote, but we are doing this since a long time without problems...

Comment: hmmm I did $git fetch origin +refs/heads/master 
and it seems that it worked...but now I can't merge with remote: $ git merge origin master    --> fatal: 'origin' does not point to a commit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As you figured out by yourself, your fetch refspec is non-standard: the "+" prefix is missing. It is *valid,* just it's not what Git sets by default, as by default it overwrites the contents of remote branches when it fetches.

   The default refspec Git adds for a named remote looks like this:

   ```
   $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```

   So you should possibly just undo what you done by hand and stick with the defaults until you really understand how refspecs and fetching work (by reading the [`git-fetch` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) at least).
2. `git merge origin master` means «merge the branches "origin" and "master" into the local branch» (doing the so-called "octopus merge").

   You either wanted `git pull origin master` (which means «fetch the branch "master" from "origin" and then merge it into the currently checked out branch») or `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/master`, where "origin/master" refers to the remote branch supposedly created/updates as the result of `git fetch origin` doing its work (subject to the first point above).

The bottom line is that it seems you tried to create a remote by editing the configuration file instead of just running `git remote add <name> <git_url>`. Don't do that unless you really understand the inner workings.

[Reading up on remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) is also essential.

Comment: Ok! I didn't edit myself the file, it was create from Eclipse, in order  to have "+" prefix, the "force update" option should be also selected, it was not default.   
The merge origin master was a typo, I don't use the console that much...thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @Glasnhost, force-updating *remote* branches when fetching is perfectly okay as the sole reason they exist is to capture (cache, if you want) the state of their own remote repository at the time you last fetched from that repository; IOW they work like bookmarks, saving you from accessing that repository each time you want to know the history of its branches. If you need to "cast in stone" a particular state of a remote branch, just fork *your* own local branch off it -- and `git fetch` won't mess with it. Hence Eclipse plays safety here for no reason really.